# Symbolic link on a USB stick automatically adding extra characters upon opening

Tags: linux, firefox, usb, symbolic-link

I'm trying to create a relative symbolic link to an html file. Both the symbolic link and the file are to be stored on a USB stick (i want it to open on any computer).

I successfully created the symbolic link by doing this:
`me@laptop: /media/administrator/2FE50BF119A67FE4$ ln -s bin/www/index.html "Khan Academy"`

Now, when I click on that link, I get the following message in the browser:

> Firefox cannot find the file at /bin/www/index.htmlZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ

WHERE in the WORLD did all those z's come from, and how can I get rid of them???????????

I've been trying to get this to work for days, I formatted a bunch of USB drives to nfts (which took forever) just so that I could create the symbolic link on the drive, and now it's not working!!

I suspect it's a bug in firefox on lubuntu. It worked perfectly on another computer running ubuntu.

Comment: Why do you think symbolic links should work in n**tf**s?

Comment: because when the drive was formated as FAT32 the permissions wouldn't allow me to create a symbolic link.

Comment: @hemflit I think I have the right syntax, ln -s TARGET LINK_NAME

Answer (score 0):

```
ln -s bin/www/index.html "Khan Academy"
```

only works if you *are positioned* at the right place, as it's a relative link. Are you sure you want to do that? (I suspect you want `/bin/www/index.html`)

Check, after you made the symbolic link, where `Khan Academy` points to with:

```
ls -al "Khan Academy"
```

I'm quite sure Firefox is the same in lubuntu as on the other machine.

Answer (score 0):

The mount point for the USB drive could be different on different machines, so you need to use a relative path. Assuming the `bin` directory is in root of your USB drive (`/media/administrator/2FE50BF119A67FE4`), the just do `ln -s ./bin/www/index.html "Khan Academy"` from the root of the USB. However, you still may not see what you expect in your browser depending on how `index.html` was written.